# Open new windows terminal with a custom color scheme

Tags: cmd, terminal, colors, color-scheme, windows-11

I've built an app that runs on cmd and uses colors but I don't like the default scheme that the terminal uses. I know that you can use custom color schemes in the new windows terminal so I was wondering if there is a way of opening an app with one without changing the default.

*Custom color schemes in new terminal:*
[image: pic of custom color schemes in terminal]

Comment: I assume from the image you've provided that Windows terminal is using the `Campbell` color scheme as its default. Why not therefore choose a different color scheme instead; e.g. `"%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe" --colorScheme [Vintage | One Half Dark | One Half Light | Tango Dark | Tango Light] …`. If you do not want any of those then you'd have to open your `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows Terminal\settings.json` file, and create a new entry with your chosen customcolor scheme and name, then use `"%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe" --colorScheme "MyCustomNameHere" …`.

Comment: `--colorScheme` was just what I wanted. I managed to open a new cmd tab by running `wt nt --colorScheme "Tango Dark" -d %~dp0 myapp.exe`, thanks.